# Clicking link inside div 2 should hide outer-div 1

Tags: html, css

I have two `div`s side by side. When a hyperlink's state is `active` (when it's clicked), I want to hide the `div` to the left, using `display: none;`.

I did this about a year ago, but since this is my first site since then, I can't remember how I did it.

I know it can be done in CSS alone, using `:active` but just not sure how anymore. How can I do this?

Comment: can you provide a jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: What i got is are you trying to do a tab ?

Comment: Not really, but thinking about it that way will result in the same thing :)

Comment: You can acheive that using css and jquery .i tried thing using jquery `http://jsfiddle.net/9qKrB/17`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the "general sibling" selector `~` in conjunction with `a:active`

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" name="trigger">Click Me</a>
<hr />
<div class="foo"></div>
<div class="bar"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
a:active ~ .foo {
    display: none;   
}
```

It basically says: find the div with a class of foo that's a sibling of the active anchor and hide it. Not to be confused with the adjacent sibling selector, `+`

View the demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/DNy2B/

Comment: that's odd, the fiddle doesn't work (IE11), it doesn't work when I test on my site either.

Comment: Indeed it is weird; I did some more experimenting and noticed that it works with `:hover` but not active, can't find much documentation on why the combination of :active and ~ doesn't work. I hate to say it but it sounds like you might need some JS.

Comment: thanks so much for your help. I love JavaScript, but the more I care about trying to cover scenarios where it may be disabled, the more it seems that I need it. Lol

Comment: I'll mark this answer as accepted, since this is actually the code I originally used about a year ago. If I can manage to get it working somehow, I will come back to update.

Comment: `:active` kind of sucks in that, even when it works, it only applies the CSS when the link is clicked on, and not when you release. One way of emulating `onClick` without JS is with checkboxes (but I dislike it because it is not semantic) - you can check out my notes here: http://www.tuanhuynh.com/blog/2013/accordions-storing-application-state-with-html-css/

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I understood your question correctly but if it is what I think you asked then do this

```
<div style="display: none;">
```

I am learning HTML, so I am kinda new and this might not be what u asked but I wanted to help so yeah :)

Answer (score -1):

This will hide/show the div when the link is clicked.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Title</title>
        <script src="jq.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#link").click(function() {
                    $("#div2").toggle();
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="div1">
            div1
            <a id="link" href="#">hey</a>
        </div>
        <div id="div2">
            div2
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```